# PHP/Laravel add array element to a multi-level associative array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have a requirement to add an element to a PHP array. I would like to know whether I have to iterate over all the elements and add it OR do I have a shortcut to get this done?

```
[
  "A": ["id": 12, "name": "test1"],
  "B": ["id": 13, "name": "test2"]
]
```

I have to add `"cut_id": 1` to each array and it should become:

```
[
  "A": ["id": 12, "name": "test1", "cut_id": 1],
  "B": ["id": 13, "name": "test2", "cut_id": 1]
]
```

Comment: I'd say you need to iterate. `foreach()` and `array_push()` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `data_fill` helper funcation

```
    $data = [
        "A" => ["id" => 12, "name" => "test1"],
        "B" => ["id" => 13, "name" => "test2"]
    ];
    data_fill($data, '*.cut_id', 1);

    dd($data);
```